# Display image with original size

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

i have a problem with display bitmap, my original image 640*960 but when i display in bitmap, size become 120*240 , how i can display with original size?

```
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), Imgid[(int)(Math.random()*Imgid.length)], options);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(position)
            iv.setImageBitmap(processingBitmap_Brightness(bitmap));
```

i log bitmap.getwidth() and getheight() but no 640*960

now i can get original size with this code , but now give me outofmemory, so i can handle the image?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //options.inSampleSize = 4;
    options.inScaled = false;
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(position);
    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Imgid[(int)(Math.random()*Imgid.length)],options);
    iv.setImageBitmap(processingBitmap_Brightness(bitmap));     
    Log.i("ID4",bitmap.getWidth()+" * "+bitmap.getHeight());
```

i used viewflipper in xml and call it in code, and addview in viewflipper

```
for (i = 0; i<5;i++) {
FrameLayout a = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER); 
a.setLayoutParams(lp);

b = new ImageView(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lpiv = new    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER); 
b.setId(i+1);
b.setLayoutParams(lpiv);
a.addView(b);

vf.addView(a);
}
```

And my onFling function

```
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1,MotionEvent e2,float velocityX,float velocityY){

    try {

        if(e1.getX() > e2.getX() && Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_in));
            vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.left_out));


            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize = 4;
            options.inScaled = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), Imgid[(int)(Math.random()*Imgid.length)], options);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(position);
            iv.setImageBitmap(processingBitmap_Brightness(bitmap));



                    vf.showPrevious();

        }else if (e1.getX() < e2.getX() && e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                    R.anim.right_in));
            vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                    R.anim.right_out));


            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize = 4;
            options.inScaled = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), Imgid[(int)(Math.random()*Imgid.length)], options);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(position);
            iv.setImageBitmap(processingBitmap_Brightness(bitmap));


                    vf.showNext();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        // nothing

    }

    return true;



}
```

Comment: 1280*800 my devices resolution

Comment: Are you using any XML to display imageview? Then show your code here

Comment: i use viewflipper in xml and in code i call my viewflipper and addview

Comment: write 'wrap_content' in imageview height and width

Comment: i update my code and u can see i use wrap content

Answer (score 1):

This official guide works great:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Basically you have to set a little smaller SampleSize than you need. Then in the next step scale the bitmap down to fit perfectly with the measures you want.

to set options.inSampleSize = 8; means that you want to load the image 1/8 the width and 1/8 the height. Therefore it is smaller.

Comment: Basically you have to set a little smaller SampleSize than you need. Then in the next step scale the bitmap down to fit perfectly with the measures you want. --> how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

[inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) is *supposed* to shrink the image. Try removing that and adding `options.inScaled = false;`

Comment: ok thanks i update my code with options.inScaled = false; n give me outofmemory if i have much image

Comment: That's normal with a lot of images in full size. There are plenty of questions/answers and efficient ways to handle bitmaps posted on this site, it's a very common problem.

Comment: yah before i used inSampleSize and my error outofmemory is gone but if i want to display image with same original size and with imagesample booth how i code that?